# ActiveRecord PostgreSQL querying an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have setup a PostgreSQL array field identical to [this example on edgeguides](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array). I am querying on these fields like:

```
Book.where("'fantasy' = ANY (tags)")
```

But what I need is to query the **inverse** of this; all records where `tags` does not include 'fantasy' (in this example).

Anyone have any guidance? I cannot find much documentation on working with a PostgreSQL array field outside of the aforementioned guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate your condition

```
Book.where("NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags))")
```

So you can modify query to get records with NULL records also:

```
Book.where("NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags)) or tags IS NULL")
```

Also you can run these queries in `psql` and check results

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags)); 
SELECT * FROM book WHERE NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags)) OR tags IS NULL; 
SELECT * FROM book WHERE 'fantasy' = ANY (tags)
```

Maybe there is no records without tag 'fantasy'?

Comment: That just returns no results unfortunately.

Comment: @TonyBeninate Try run these queries in psql 
SELECT * FROM book WHERE NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags));
SELECT * FROM book WHERE 'fantasy' = ANY (tags)
Maybe there is no records without tag 'fantasy'?

Comment: I was using the "book/fantasy" example as way of staying constant with the Edgeguides, that's not my actual data, I'm using `archived_by` which contains an array value; however, I have plenty records where the equivalent "tag" is blank: 

`user.conversations.last(10).map(&:archived_by)
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, [359034]]`

Comment: So you can modify query to get records with NULL records also: 

Book.where("NOT('fantasy' = ANY (tags)) or tags IS NULL")

Comment: SHOOT — I need to run some more testing but at first glance this appears to be working!

Comment: If you can update your answer to reflect the above, I'll accept it. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Book.where.not('tags @> ARRAY[?]', "fantasy")
```

Comment: This is the approach I had been trying to get working myself, but for some reason this returns no results here.